# Find most repeated ! np.array ! in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, scipy

I saw some solutions on finding the most common scalar in an numpy array using scipy.stats.mode / np.bincount / collections.counter.

But I am not able to apply these on my porblem.

Having an list of numpy arrays like

```
 list_name = [np.array([1,2,3]),
         np.array([1,2,3]),
         np.array([5,6,7]),
         np.array([1,2,3]),
         np.array([2,3,4]),
         np.array([2,3,4])]
```

I would like to find the most repeated vector -> `np.array([1,2,3])` in the case shown above.

Thanks for your help on this!

Martin

Comment: Would the number elements per array be the same?

Comment: `list` is a Python data structure. It is not a good practice to name objects after keywords or data structures.

Comment: 1) Yes, number of elements per np.array are always the same. 2) You are right, bad choice for a name ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First convert the list of vectors to a matrix.

```
mtx = np.matrix(list)
```

Get unique values with counts

```
values, counts = np.unique(mtx, return_counts=True, axis=0)
```

Retrieve the most common value

```
values[counts==np.max(counts),]
```